# How to Override catalog_category_view.xml file in our theme?

Tags: category

I have tried, it is working in base folder. but doesn't work in my custom theme fronted folder.

Comment: Have you tried this **vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

Comment: I dont want extend layout xml, I want to override it completely and following this as reference, any idea 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to copy the catalog_product_view.xml to your custom theme. Please copy it under:

> app/design/frontend/{{Package}}/{{theme}}/Magento_Catalog/layout

Put only the required part to this xml and modify as required.

Also make sure if the same xml/block is not being overwritten in other module.

Comment: this is Extend layout method but I want to use Override method..please review this url https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy catalog_category_view.xml to your custom theme.

path: app/design/frontend/{{theme directory name}}/{{theme name }}/Magento_Catalog/layout